# HTML Set Image Center On Div

Tags: html, css

Hello i want to set img center on div like facebook

my code

```
<div style='border: 1px solid #BFBFBF; background-color: #fff; width: 600px; height: 300px;text-align: center; ' >

    <img src='http://www.trendycovers.com/covers/fear_is_a_lie_facebook_cover_1463215575.jpg' style='max-width: 600px; max-height: 300px; '>

</div>
```

My Image:
[image]

See Facebook:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need :

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

check this link for example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4570/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
val = ($('div').height() - $('img').height()) / 2;
$('img').css('top', val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution

Add this css to your img styles:

```
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Final Code:

```
<div style='border: 1px solid #BFBFBF; background-color: #fff; width: 600px; height: 300px;text-align: center; ' >
    <img src='http://www.trendycovers.com/covers/fear_is_a_lie_facebook_cover_1463215575.jpg' style='max-width: 600px;max-height: 300px;position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);'>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3ohj2nzo/